# Creating list with dictionary instead of multiple dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having difficulties with the output format of the program

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    data = pd.read_json("/home/mahmoud/Desktop/FB.json", orient='records')

    company_name = data['dataset']['name']
    columns_names = data['dataset']['column_names']
    stock_data = data['dataset']['data']

    data_list = []

    for rows in range(len(stock_data)):
        for columns in range(12):
            dataValues = {columns_names[columns]:stock_data[rows][columns]}
            data_list.append(dataValues)

    for val in range(len(data_list)):
        print(data_list[val])

if __name__=='__main__':main()
```

When i run this program I get the following output, every entry is a dictionary by itself:
`{'Date': '2018-12-11'}`
`{'Open': 143.88}`
`{'High': 143.88}`
`{'Low': 141.1}`
`{'Close': 142.08}`
`{'Volume': 20300349.0}`
`{'Dividend': 0.0}`
`{'Split': 1.0}`
`{'Adj_Open': 143.88}`
`{'Adj_High': 143.88}`
`{'Adj_Low': 141.1}`
`{'Adj_Close': 142.08}`

I am trying to output the following: `[{'Date':2018-12-11, 'Open':143.88, 'High':143.88, 'Low':141.1, 'Close':142.08, 'Volume':20300349.0, 'Dividend':0.0, 'Split':1.0, 'Adj_Open':143.88, 'Adj_High':143.88, 'Adj_Low':141.1, 'Adj_Close':142.08},
{'Date':22018-12-10, 'Open':139.6, 'High':143.05, 'Low':139.01, 'Close':141.85, 'Volume':26422173.0, 'Dividend':0.0, 'Split':1.0, 'Adj_Open':139.6, 'Adj_High':143.05, 'Adj_Low':139.01, 'Adj_Close':141.85}]`

These are the contents of the variables stock_data and columns_names

stock_data: `[['2018-12-11', 143.88, 143.88, 141.1, 142.08, 20300349.0, 0.0, 1.0, 143.88, 143.88, 141.1, 142.08, 20300349.0], ['2018-12-10', 139.6, 143.05, 139.01, 141.85, 26422173.0, 0.0, 1.0, 139.6, 143.05, 139.01, 141.85]]`

columns_names: `['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Dividend', 'Split', 'Adj_Open', 'Adj_High', 'Adj_Low', 'Adj_Close', 'Adj_Volume']`

Comment: Your indentation is off. Please provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Likely because all the keys are the same and then you will only see the value associated with the last key. Perhaps post some example data and what you expect the data frame to look like

Comment: This is because in the innermost loop statement, you're using the same key but writing different values to it. By the time the inner for loop completes the key of the dictionary is the last value is list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be as simple as using one list comprehension (the outter list) and one dictionary comprehension (the inner dicts). Just iterate over each row in `stock_data` and for each row iterate **simultanously** (using *zip*) over the values of the current row and the columns names. All of that could be done using standard for loops, like in the code you posted, but that will be far more verbose; besides, the comprehensions below aren't that hard to read.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    data = pd.read_json("/home/mahmoud/Desktop/FB.json", orient='records')

    company_name = data['dataset']['name']
    columns_names = data['dataset']['column_names']
    stock_data = data['dataset']['data']

    # Here is the change
    data_list = [{c: v for c, v in zip(columns_names, r)} for r in stock_data]

    for val in data_list:
        print(val, data_list[val])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope this finally help you!

Comment: data_dict[column_name[columns]] = stock_data[rows][columns], I tried it and it still prints the last elements only. I need a way to be able to add elements without removing the old data that I have stored.

Comment: In fact, the above code will throw an error because the last loop will try to access to `dataValue`, which is not defined. Sorry, I will edit.

Comment: I edited the code for the for loop but it still prints only the last set of values.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Rahman sorry, finally I could understand your problem. You need to invert those two for loops. Create a list for each column and the fill it with each value of the current row

Comment: Cortina Sorry I haven't been clear of what I want. What I want the output data to look like is this: [{'Date':2018-12-11, 'Open':143.88, 'High':143.88, 'Low':141.1, 'Close':142.08, 'Volume':20300349.0, 'Dividend':0.0, 'Split':1.0, 'Adj_Open':143.88, 'Adj_High':143.88, 'Adj_Low':141.1, 'Adj_Close':142.08},
{'Date':22018-12-10, 'Open':139.6, 'High':143.05, 'Low':139.01, 'Close':141.85, 'Volume':26422173.0, 'Dividend':0.0, 'Split':1.0, 'Adj_Open':139.6, 'Adj_High':143.05, 'Adj_Low':139.01, 'Adj_Close':141.85}]. I have adjusted the code so I will re-post the code.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Rahman I edited the code again after you updated your question. Is that what solves your problem? If not, please, tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you reset your `dataValues` after each iteration, so it's wiping out what was previously stored. You'll need to append the `dataValues` into your initial dictionary that you setup `data_dict = {}`. You never do anything with that in the code, I'm assuming thats where your trying to put all those **value:keys**

```
import pandas as pd

def main():

data = pd.read_json("/home/mahmoud/Desktop/FB.json", orient='records')

    company_name = data['dataset']['name']
    columns_names = data['dataset']['column_names']
    stock_data = data['dataset']['data']

    data_dict = {}

    for rows in range(len(stock_data)):
        for columns in range(12):
                dataValues = {column_name[columns]:stock_data[rows][columns]}
                # now take your dataValues, and add that to your data_dict below
                CODE GOES HERE

    for val in dataValues:
        print(val, dataValues[val])

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: I understand the error, but I can't append dataValues to data_dict. I tried the following dataValues = {columns_names[columns]:stock_data[rows][columns]}
data_dict = dataValues
and still not working, how can I append the data to data_dict